# Remove table layout in html plain text

Tags: html

I have created an email signature with 7 columns in a TR.
when sent it as plain text mode, the space for 7 rows remains in the plain text mode email signature. can i remove this 7 rows when it comes to plain text mode?

Comment: `the space for 7 rows` - Did you means Columns? You may get some luck  using CSS but it depends on the client etc https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Yes i inserted 7 columns to same TR. I did it only for insert background color. most of our clients use outlook. how it be helped to me to insert the ccs coding?

Comment: I'm lost, your post says 7 rows?! Can you edit it and make it columns (if it should be)

Comment: when it views in plain text mode, the columns automatically convert into rows.

Comment: You are probably better asking this on StackOverflow (but don't cross post, delete this and then re-ask there). I think you'll have more luck there :)

Comment: @NiroshChami Can you share the code which you have used.